# See running procedure in SQL server Profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler

How can I see running procedures in SQL Server Profiler?

It only shows when the execution is done.

I have some procedures that requires my attention if it is taking too long to get executed. Getting to know after it is done is useless for me

thanks

Answer (score 5):

SQL Profiler can definitely show you which statements, procs and batches are running before they complete.

Ensure that the template you select in profiler has the [applicable events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190176.aspx), to see when statements / procs start, i.e.

- SQL:StmtStarting
- SP:Starting
- SP:StmtStarting (to view statements in the SPROC)

In addition to the `*Completed` events. Obviously metrics such as duration, cpu, io etc aren't available in the Starting events.

You can also select these events by changing the `Properties` and selecting these from the `Events` tab. If you a profiling a very busy server, ensure that you apply filters like `DatabaseName`, `HostName` or even `SPID` if you are fortunate enough to be able to isolate it (you may need to check `Show All Events` and `columns` checkboxes)

Comment: thanks, Am I able to setup to show for how the proc/statement/batch is running and still running? ( I don't mean duration, which of course, doesn't make sense because it has to be done )

Comment: @EdwinSoho if you can isolate your SPID, then I would suggest you enable `SP:StmtStarting` and `SP:StmtCompleted` as well - this will show each completed statement in your SPROC, which should help isolate your bottleneck.

Comment: I got it, but the problem is, it will retrieve a lot of garbage in the profile result. I don't have the specifics procs/statements to filter